# Django object.id does not match with the objects used in reverse url look up

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model "Listing" which represents companies, also another model "lead" which represents different projects that can be assigned to companies. They are associated via many to many relationship since a company can be assigned to many leads as well many leads can be associated with many other companies. Models are listed below.

Leads are displayed in listing admin page as inline elements. Also there is snippet used to display a link directly to lead edit page of the object which is done through reverse url.

Problem is the object.id argument is always wrong not corresponding to the leads id but some other number.

[image]

In the image above the lead look up id is shown as "53".But in reality it is 78. Any pointers to what i may be missing would be appreciated.

[image]

```
#admin.py    
def url_to_edit_object(self,object):
                    #info = (object._meta.app_label, object._meta.module_name)
                    admin_url = reverse('admin:dirapp_lead_change',  args=(object.id,))
                    return u'<a href="%s">Edit</a>' %(admin_url)
```

LEAD MODEL:

```
class lead(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(Listing,blank=True, null=True, related_name="leads")
    requested_software = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_pos = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=NO_OF_POS, default='1')
    type_of_business = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TYPE_OF_BUSINESS, default='Bar NightClub', blank=True, null=True)
    time_frame = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TIME_FRAME, default='1')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.business_name
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('listing_detail', (),
                    {
                        'slug' :self.slug,
                        })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.business_name)
            super(lead, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Listing Model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
        """
        Base model for listings 

        """
        STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        )
        status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
        submitted_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="associates")
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        point = models.PointField(geography=True,srid=settings.SRID, blank=True, null=True)
        point2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
        zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
        industry = models.ManyToManyField(indCat, related_name="category", blank=True, null=True)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        objects = models.GeoManager()
        tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
        search = SphinxSearch()

        def __unicode__(self):
                #return "%s %s %s"%(self.title, self.point.x, self.point.y)
                return "%s"%(self.title)
        @models.permalink
        def get_absolute_url(self):
                return ('listing_detail', (),
                    {
                        'slug' :self.slug,
                        })

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.slug:
                        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
                if not self.point:
                        location = "%s+%s+%s+%s"%(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
                        cord = get_lat_long(location)
                        #x,y = cord.split(",")
                        lat = float(cord[0])
                        lng = float(cord[1])
                        #x = float(lat)
                        #y = float(lng) 
                        self.point = Point(lng,lat)
                        self.point2 = Point(lng,lat)
                super(Listing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Dirapp admin.py:

```
class ListingImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ListingImage



class AssignedLeads(admin.TabularInline):
        model = lead.assigned_to.through 
        extra = 0
        #list_select_related = True
        def url_to_edit_object(self,object):
                #info = (object._meta.app_label, object._meta.module_name)
                admin_url = reverse('admin:dirapp_lead_change',  args=(object.id,))
                return u'<a href="%s">Edit</a>' %(admin_url)
        url_to_edit_object.allow_tags = True
        list_display = ('business_name','url_to_edit_object',)
        readonly_fields = ('url_to_edit_object',)       
class leadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ('city', 'state')
    list_display = ('business_name','first_name','last_name','city','state','submission_date')
    list_filter = ('city', 'state','submission_date', 'assigned_to')
    inlines = [leadUpdateInline]
    filter_horizontal = ('assigned_to',)

class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug":("title",)}
    inlines = [leadUpdateInline,ListingImageInline, AssignedLeads]
    filter_horizontal = ('submitted_by',)
    class Media:
        js = (settings.STATIC_URL+'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                 settings.STATIC_URL+"filebrowser/js/TinyMCEAdmin.js",
                 settings.STATIC_URL+"tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tinymce_setup.js")


class EmailReminderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_filter = ('lead', 'company','email_date_time')

admin.site.register(lead,leadAdmin)
admin.site.register(Listing,ListingAdmin)
admin.site.register(indCat)
admin.site.register(email_reminder, EmailReminderAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `url_to_edit_object` method, `object` is not a `Lead` instance - it's an instance of the intermediate model that stores the many to many data.

Use `object.lead_id` instead.